# Pub Sub Emulator Not downloading with actions/cache@v3 using node version 20

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, firebase-tools

I have the following github action using node 20

```
name: develop-pr

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop

env:
  CI: true
  FIREBASE_EMULATORS_PATH: $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/emulator-cache

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 30
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [20.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Extract branch name
        shell: bash
        run: echo "##[name=branch >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT;]$(echo ${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/})"
        id: extract_branch

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: "Cache npm"
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        env:
          cache-name: cache-node-modules
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ matrix.node-version }}-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}

      - name: "Cache Emulators"
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ env.FIREBASE_EMULATORS_PATH }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-firebase-emulators-${{ hashFiles('emulator-cache/*.{jar,zip}') }}
        continue-on-error: true

      - name: Setup Firebase CLI
        run: sudo npm install -g firebase-tools@12.4.0

      - name: Install
        working-directory: ./functions
        run: npm install

      - name: Lint
        working-directory: ./functions
        run: npm run lint

      - name: Test
        working-directory: ./functions
        run: npm run test

      - name: Print debug logs
        if: failure()
        run: find . -type f -name "*debug.log" | xargs cat
```

But each time the github action runs, i get the following error

> Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile
> /home/runner/work/project-firebase/project-firebase/functions/$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/emulator-cache/pubsub-emulator-0.1.0/pubsub-emulator/lib/cloud-pubsub-emulator-0.1-SNAPSHOT-all.jar

[image]